# Is there a way to add regular index numbers to a dataframe with dates as the index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am working with dataframes for a uni assignment, but do not have a lot of experience with it. One of the datasets we use automatically puts the date as the index, as you can see in the [screenshot of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQElS.jpg). I have to work with if- and for-loops, which works better with a regular index. I can't find anywhere how I can transform the date index into a regular column, and add normal index numbers. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_sleep_2.reset_index()
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

You can either set the parameter `inplace=True` to directly modify the dataframe, or assign it to a new variable e.g.

```
# modify dataframe in place
df_sleep_2.reset_index(inplace=True)

# or assign result to new variable
df_sleep_2_new_index = df_sleep_2.reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! I didn't add 'inplace=True', that's why it didn't work initially

Answer (score 0):

try to reset the index using reset_index

```
df_sleep_2.reset_index()
```